# D3 bar chart and using multiple scales

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

I'm creating a "trending" analysis bar chart using d3.  This chart has an X axis in the middle, and bars that can extend either above or below this axis to represent percentage change.  I've done this by using 3 scales - an ordinal for the X axis, and two linear scales for the Y axis.  The usage of the *two* linear scales is what I'm uncertain about.  It seems inelegant and just "not right."

The scales in question:

```
this.pyscale.domain([0, 1]);
this.pyscale.rangeRound([this.height/2, 0]);

this.nyscale.domain([-1, 0]);
this.nyscale.rangeRound([this.height, this.height/2]);
```

Functions related to drawing the bars:

```
bar.append("rect")
   .attr("y", function(d) { 
        if (d[that.ycol] >= 0) {
            return that.pyscale(d[that.ycol]);
        }
        return that.height/2; 
    })
   .attr("height", function(d) { 
        if (d[that.ycol] >= 0) {
            return that.height/2 - that.pyscale(d[that.ycol]);
        }
        return that.nyscale(d[that.ycol]) - that.height/2;
    })
   .attr("width", this.xscale.rangeBand())
```

Is this a decent way to do this?  Or is there a more elegant way using one Y scale that I'm missing?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score -1):

From your description, it sounds like you should be able to replace your two scales with one scale simply like this:

```
this.yscale.domain([-1, 1]);
this.yscale.rangeRound([this.height, 0]);
```

and use `this.yscale` in the rest of the code.

Comment: To clarify: you'll still need to decide whether to position the top of the rectangle based on the value (positive), or at the zero line (negative): `yscale( Math.max(0, d[that.ycol] ) )` should work.  For the height of the rectangle, you could use `Math.abs( yscale(d[that.ycol]) - yscale(0) )`.

Comment: Good catch, I had missed that!

Comment: Code would be so much simpler if we could just use a negative height or width to mean "draw in the opposite direction from normal", but no such luck.